# Not able to findById while using the query through spring jpa hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have table SEQUENCE which stores meta data for sequences for other tables. We query this table to get the latest sequence not sure why it was done this now a days we have sequence generators. Anyways so when I try to use findById passing the table name parameter it returns null. Any idea why would it not read the table at all. When I try to query using oracle developer editor it works fine. What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**
So i figured we are using the custom tabel sequence generator. So i'm trying to use @TableGenerator :

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
            generator = "table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator",
            table = "sequence",
            pkColumnName = "seq_table",
            valueColumnName = "seq_last_seq")
```

SEQUENCE table : SEQ_TABLE, SEQ_LAST_SEQ, SEQ_INCREMENT

Now the problem is since this table SEQUENCE have additional column SEQ_INCREMENT for which i'm getting this error :
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA NAME"."SEQUENCE"."SEQ_INCREMENT")
The SEQUENCE table has SEQ_INCREMENT column set to NOT NULL. How do i make sure with update the column is not set to null

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the table name as parameter.

When you define your model, in that file you say what is the table name:
[image]

In my case my model is called *Call* and the table name is called *calls*.

Create a repository like that :
[image]

The repository already have some default "queries" you can use, if you want to do findById, you just need to call it and pass the ID.

[image]

Comment: RIght. Now i have figured it's the SEQUENCE default table I'm trying to query. So i need to use @TableGenerator